# intersection of multiple sets in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, intersection

Ok, so I want/need to use the "|: operator

Say I have a list:

```
list = [{1,2,3},{2,3,4},{3,4,5},{4,5,6}]
```

I need to find the intersection of the list without using: 
    set.intersection(*L)

Ideally I'd like to use a function with a for loop (or nested for loops) to get return the intersections of all of the sets in the list:

```
isIntersction(L) = {1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

Thanks

Comment: That's not the intersection, it's the union

Comment: Why do you want to "ideally us a function with a for loop"? Does your homework say you have to? because there's nothing "ideal" about doing it that way

Comment: 1) yes, it is a union, my bad, and 2, it needs to be in the form:

def isUnion(L):
union = {}
for i in L:
   (code here)
return variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using list comprehension

```
list = [{1,2,3},{2,3,4},{3,4,5},{4,5,6}]
b = []
[b.append(x) for c in list for x in c if x not in b]
print b # or set(b)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

If you are keen on having the output as a set, try this:

```
b = set([])
[b.add(x) for c in list for x in c if x not in b]
print b
```

Output:

```
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) #or {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

If you want a function try this:

```
def Union(L):
    b = []
    [b.append(x) for c in L for x in c if x not in b]
    return set(b)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  I changed it around to the long form:

`def myUnion(L):
    union = []
    for i in L:
        for j in i:
            if i not in union:
                union.append(i)
    return set(union)`

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> L=[{1,2,3},{2,3,4},{3,4,5},{4,5,6}]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> set(chain.from_iterable(L))
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in `reduce`:

```
>>> L = [{1,2,3},{2,3,4},{3,4,5},{4,5,6}]
>>> reduce(set.union, L, set())
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```